# Running small Operation on task/thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, delay

I am recording audio from IP Phones, writing in c#.

I have a method that runs for each packet the I capture (A LOT of packets). the method fills the buffer with the payload data.

```
public void HandlePayload(byte[] payload, IpV4Address dstIp)
{
    count++;
    // packet from source
    if (dstIp == _dstIp)
    {
        AddPayloadToArray(MuLawDecoder.MuLawDecode(payload), ArrayType.SRC_PCM);
        // Task.Run(() =>AddPayloadToArray(MuLawDecoder.MuLawDecode(payload), ArrayType.SRC_PCM));
    }

    // packet from destination
    if (dstIp == _srcIp)
    {
        AddPayloadToArray(MuLawDecoder.MuLawDecode(payload), ArrayType.DST_PCM);
        // Task.Run(() =>AddPayloadToArray(MuLawDecoder.MuLawDecode(payload), ArrayType.DST_PCM));
    }
 }
```

**EDIT : The Play Method**

```
public void PlayCall(SkinnyCall call)
{
    Waveout.Play();
    byte[] mixedBuffer = new byte[320];
    while (_playerIndex < call.AudioArrays[(int)ArrayType.Pcm].Length)
    {
        if (_state == PlayerState.Paused || _state == PlayerState.Stopped)
            // call either paused or stopped
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < 320; i++)
        {
            mixedBuffer[i] = (byte)(call.AudioArrays[(int)ArrayType.Pcm][_playerIndex + i];
        }
        _playerIndex += 320;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        AddSamples(mixedBuffer);
        ClearByteArray(ref mixedBuffer);
    }
    if (_playerIndex == call.AudioArrays[(int)ArrayType.Pcm])
    {
        // call has finished and Playback is over
        StopCall(call);
        PlaybackEnded();
    }
}
```

I need a way to run it on  a different thread/task because when I run it normally (on the same thread) there is delay after a while and its getting bigger.

I tried to use Task.run each time I run it, but it did problems.

Basically, looking for a way to have one thread/task that its job will be to run only those operations, and nothing else, without having to do New Thread everytime.

and to be able to pass parameters to it every time.

any thoughts? been struggling with this for a while..

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a producer-consumer queue to synchronize work between two threads. `BlockingCollection` in particular makes code like this a breeze.

However, you're more likely running into a different issue - you should be able to process the data in real-time on one thread just fine. Make sure the performance problem actually is where you think it is, measure the time you lose in each part of your code. Using `Task.Run` is not the best idea, but it would work (and it does not actually create new threads - it reuses threads from the thread-pool).

Depending on your memory usage pattern, you might even be running into issues with the garbage collector. `CLRProfiler` will help you determine that, and you might also want to investigate how you're using the `byte[]` buffers you're passing around - if you're not actually copying it anywhere and are only passing a reference to the original buffer, multi-threading will mean you'll get your data rewritten before it has a chance to be processed.

The golden rule is - measure. Profile. Find out *why* you're getting delayed. The `Task` infrastructure is actually incredibly fast, so it's quite unlikely that's the bottleneck. Guessing won't get you far, especially if you don't actually have much experience with this kind of problem.

Comment: thanks for you comment! I changed my code a little bit and now its better but still not perfect: I still do Task.Run for each packet that I capture, but the difference is that before the change I was running the PLAY method (which is a long one) on Task.run, and realized that Task.Run is not made for long operations. Now the PLAY method is running on a new thread that I created. no delay - but the thing is when I play it, the voice is really slow and broken. I play it from the byte array. do you think its because I am doing Task.Run too many times? or not handling the Thread? thnaks!

Comment: How big are the packets? You probably want to wait for a certain minimum amount of data before you start the playback. Make sure you can playback fluently across packets too - the delays between two packets will be very audible (causing cracking and slowdowns).

Comment: thanks. no delay, but I think the Playback is bad because I am doing tons of Task.Run (for each packet process). you think I should stay with this for the Packet Process? or maybe have a Thread only for those operations?

Comment: Actually, `Task.Run` has very little overhead. And if you don't hear any delays, that most likely means you really are having trouble with very small pauses. How do you handle the playback? Are you filling a buffer continuously that never gets empty, or are you doing successive calls to some play method that only works on one payload at a time?

Comment: I edited my post and added the Play Method. now its like this - I run the packet process in Task.run and the Play method in a new thread. only one issue - the playback is sometimes broken when I play while the call is still going (probably because the Task.run is happening all the time). once the call is done - the playback is much better (because there is no more packets and so no more Task.run operations). BTW - the Thread.sleep(20) is because the RTP protocol has a 20 ms delay. thanks!

Comment: Be very careful about `Thread.Sleep` - it's not guaranteed to return in 20 ms. In fact, most of the time, it simply will not - the default timer resolution is 15ms, so the resolution around such small values is very poor, and that's before you take multi-tasking into account - your thread can sleep for much longer than 20 ms (under high load conditions with just normal priority threads, I think the maximum should be around 200 ms, but in reality it's probably unbounded). Why do you even care about the delay? You'll just get stuck on I/O for a bit, right?

Comment: I do the Thread.sleep(20) because the RTP Protocol has a 20ms delay so if I dont do the sleep - the Play method will be faster than the capturing of the RTP and I will finish playing back the call while its not over yet (still going). the playback will just stop when i reach the end of the buffer, but its because the playing is faster than the capturing

Comment: @user1662033: Yeah, you shouldn't be doing that. In fact, you want to have the delay longer, but not per-packet. Buffer under-run is going to cause tons of audible issues. If you wait for 500ms before starting to play the data, you'll have better chance of avoiding under-runs during playback. But only on the beginning of a new stream of data, not on each packet. That's pretty much the whole point of buffering the audio data.

Comment: thanks. I will try that. one more thing - now I do Task.run for each Packet process - and I know you said it has very little overhead - but still when I do it for each packet the processing is actually slower than when I do it without Task.run. I used Task.run in order to avoid the delay of the capturing.  now I think I should probably use some Task scheduler or one Task that its job will be the processing, instead of doing millions of Task.run - and going every time to the Thread-pool.

Comment: because now (wit the Task.run) the Play method actually runs faster than the capturing, so the Play method ends while the call still runs.

Comment: @user1662033 Well, you obviously want to execute those `Play` calls sequentially. Again, creating a buffer that's played on one thread and written to on another is a better solution. But if you want to stay with `Task.Run`, use the exclusive part of `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` - it will make sure the calls are sequential rather than concurrent.

Comment: I got it to work! the problem was the Array.resize method that I do for each packet  is taking way too long. Apparently, if you have more than 500 items in the collection its better to use List<byte>, and than just do List.Add - more efficient. Thanks for your time and your answers!

Comment: Hah, yeah, that's exactly why you want to use a constant size buffer :) `Array.Resize` simply creates a whole new array and copies the old one into the new one. `List.Add` is only more efficient because it doesn't expand by exactly as much as you ask, but rather a bit more - leading to less total copies.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is creating second Thread and pass your data there via [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can look at msdn example.

But this require a lot of manual multi-thread work. I personally recommend you to look at [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is pretty awesome framework for such tasks

Here is a quick example how to create and use TPL Dataflow

```
// Create bufferBlock for store
BufferBlock<byte[]> _inputBufferBytes = new BufferBlock<byte[]>();

// Create action block for job
ActionBlock<byte[]> _inputBufferParcer = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(bytes => ProcessInputBuffer(bytes));

// Link one block to another 
// from [_inputBufferBytes] to [_inputBufferParcer]
_inputBufferBytes.LinkTo(_inputBufferParcer);

...

// add new bytes to buffer
_inputBufferBytes.Post(buffer);
```

you can freely post data to BufferBlock from any thread and they will be parsed in FIFO way asynchronously in ActionBlock. There are a several kinds of blocks like `TransformBlock<in,out>`, or `BatchBlock` which generates arrays of data. I recommend you to read the manuals, TPL Dataflow may be quite powerfull.

Comment: Thnaks for your comment! I will try that